# Trying to use list comprehension to convert list of strings to integers?

Tags: python, list, matrix

I'm trying to use list comprehension to convert all values in a matrix list of lists to integers.  The following is a snippet of code from a program that reads in a txt file consisting of lines of numbers seperated by spaces:

```
def readMatrix(file):
    contents = open(file).read()
    return [item.split() for item in contents.split("\n")]
    return [int(item) for item in contents]
```

When I try to do arithmetic on the lists in another function of my program I get:

> ```
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
> ```

Comment: Please show the actual code. There is no `+` in your program.

Comment: Your second `return` statements in the function will be ignored entirely. You are not using `+` anywhere in your function.

Comment: Your first `return` statement produces a list of lists with *strings*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want probably this:

```
def readMatrix(file):
    with open(file) as contents:
        return [[int(item) for item in line.split()] for line in contents]
```